# Join twice a relation with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, entity-attribute-value

I have a couple of tables:

```
table items: id, title
table properties: id_item, name, value
```

So an item has multiple properties (is an EAV).

Now i need to find which item has some properties, so i try to join the same relation multiple times:

```
    $queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
        ->join('i.properties', 'p');

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($properties as $name=>$value) {
        $queryBuilder->join('i.properties', 'p'.$i)
            ->andWhere("p{$i}.name = :name".$i)
            ->setParameter(':name'.$i, $name)
            ->andWhere("p{$i}.value = :value".$i)
            ->setParameter(':value'.$i, $value);
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
    return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But this doesn't work because the join is not repeated by doctrine, it uses always the same.

**UPDATE:**

To be more clear, if I join only once the table item and properties I get:

```
id | title   | name | value
 1 | t shirt | color| red
 1 | t shirt | size | large
```

But if i need to search the items that have property color=red and size=large, i need to join it twice, so that i can make more where condition on different columns:

```
id | title   | name1 | value1 | name2 | value2
 1 | t shirt | color | red    | size  | large
```

The SQL generate actually is something like:

```
SELECT m0_.id AS id0
FROM item m0_
INNER JOIN properties m1_ ON m0_.id = m1_.item_id
WHERE m1_.name = 'Color' AND m1_.value = 'red' AND m1_.name = 'Size' AND m1_.value = 'Large'
```

But obviously `m1_.name` cannot be Color and Size at the same time.

Comment: what have you got when `print $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getSql()` ?

Comment: In the foreach statement you have a variable "$properies". That should probably be "$properties" with a "t".

Comment: typo fixed (but I'm changing the names for the example, the typo wasn't in the original code) @LorenzSchaef

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo I added the Sql generated

Comment: I will approach to this question from other point of view, not related to question itself, but, I would suggest you to think again to your db structure. Just to ask a question, how you would recognize situations where a red t-shirt ins't in stock for large size?